# Crowd Sourcing Application Waze

Tags: architecture

Waze is a crowed sourcing application for traffic and alerts. I am building something similar to Waze but my question is that when people notify about different kind of alerts and they appear on the map how do these alerts go away. Are they time based or some user (actual person) marks them invalid?

Comment: Looks like StackOverFlow is a cruel place for beginners!

Comment: It's a cruel place for people who don't do any legwork. It's not a coding service, it's a Q&A site for specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for someone who doesn't have the source code to tell you **conclusively** how this works.  That being said, you can probably reason your way through it with a little bit of research and common sense.

As of June 2013, [Waze had nearly 50 million users](http://news.yahoo.com/waze-sale-signals-growth-israeli-high-tech-174533585.html).

Around the same time, [Waze had about 115 employees](http://www.quora.com/How-many-employees-does-Waze-have-as-of-May-2013).

Though highly unlikely, let's imagine that all 115 employees had the sole responsibility of deleting alerts for 40 hours a week.  So 115 people * 40 hours * 60 minutes = 276,000 possible minutes that could be spent per week manually deleting alerts.  Let's imagine (conservatively) that each user generates 1 alert per week.  That's 50,000,000 alerts generated per week.  50,000,000 alerts /276,000 minutes = 181 alert per minute = 3 alerts per second.  That's how fast every employee of Waze would need to manually delete alerts if the only thing any employee of Waze ever did was manually delete alerts.

Within a couple months after both of these numbers (employee count and user count) were published, [Google spent over a billion dollars to purchase Waze](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/11/behind-the-maps-whats-in-a-waze-and-why-did-google-just-pay-a-billion-for-it/).

Now, as I said - it's impossible for someone who doesn't have the source code to tell you conclusively exactly how Waze works.  But, intuitively, it does seem like it would be strange for anyone to spend all that money on a company comprised of 115 people clicking a mouse at least three times a second with little to no time for considering any other aspect of the business.  But, your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score -1):

Well think about this for a second. It's crowd sourced. So that means what? We use people in the crowd! In other words, an employee has nothing to do with the hazards reported. At first, it's time based. If after a certain amount of time nobody has "thumbs up'd" it, it disappears. A "thumbs up" extends the amount of time needed until the report disappears on its own. But if the hazard doesn't exist, Wazers can hit "Not There" and the report will disappear.

My suggestion if you want to try and mimic Waze, just download the app and use it for a month.